# how to remove unused test accounts from Metamask

Tags: metamask

i use metamask chrome extension with testRPC to do my testing

now metamask have over 20 dead accounts just sitting there in the list

my question how to you clear loose unused test accounts from Metamask

Comment: Perhaps some day they'll add a "Remove Token" button?

Comment: I have a related question. I restored my account with seed but lost other accounts. How do I access them?

Comment: Question: Does the method provided by TripleSpeeder delete your accounts with funds in it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To clear all extra addresses:

1. Take note of your 12 word seedphrase if you intent to use the same
   addresses again
2. Make sure your account is locked (Click "Lock" in
   top right menu)
3. In the unlock screen, click "Forgot password"
4. Enter your 12 word seed phrase
5. Set a new password (or use the same you used before)

Now only the first account is visible.

**Edit:**

In more recent versions of MetaMask you'll find a simple delete function in the account menu:

1. If necessary, back-up the private key (Open account menu > Account details > Export private key)
2. Select the account you want to delete
3. Open account menu
4. Select Remove account

**Additional info:** You can only remove imported accounts and external accounts that you imported with private keys or JSON (such as a hardware wallet). Accounts that you've added using the 'Create Account' button in MetaMask cannot be removed

Comment: My first thought was to scoff and say what a ridiculously bad UI.. however, on second thought, I suppose it's good idea that they don't let you accidentally delete your money that easily.

Comment: @flakes ok, not easily makes sense, but having to delete all accounts if you just want to remove a couple doesn't make any sense

Comment: "Now **only the first account** is visible."  You might as well just reinstall the plugin.  It's a horrible UI.  Of course reinstall the plugin *only* after saving the private keys (or JSON files and passwords) to all your used accounts.

Comment: Now, a year later, is it any better?

Comment: horrible extension, would never use Metamask if I didn't had to but users request it

Comment: Looks like this no longer works in MetaMask version 8.x

Comment: still works as of March 2021

Comment: presumably customer login, similar with no export account function. it is disgusting web2 stuff

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can - MetaMask currently doesn't have very advanced ID management.

A [recent thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5zakin/i_cant_figure_out_how_to_delete_accounts_from/) on Reddit, I believe involving certain MetaMask devs, had this to say:

> If you are uncomfortable seeing too many empty accounts, (after
>   securely backing up your seed phrase with redundancy) you can
>   re-generate the wallet from seed and only add as many as you prefer.
>   (You may also want to back up private keys individually for good
>   measure before doing anything drastic.)

Answer (score 3):

Siple way is to uninstall plugin and install again - it worked for me

BACKUP YOUR SEED PHRASE FIRST !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Note that will also clear all your transactions.